# Resultset in RowMapper For JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, rowmapper

I'm trying to understand how JdbcCursorItemReader works. I noticed that the ItemReader read() method eventually calls readCursor() method from JdbcCursorItemReader where we pass the **complete** **resultset** and current position of record to be read to rowMapper. RowMapper interface documentation says that we aren't supposed to call next on resultset and the resultset param is pre-initialized for **current row**. How and in which class is spring doing this pre-initialization?

JdbcCursorItemReader - passing complete resultset everytime read() is called
[image]

[image: RowMapper -]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization happens in `JdbcCursorItemReader#openCursor`. The reader is responsible of the ResultSet's lifecycle as well as advancing the pointer to the next row if any.

The mapper is given the `ResultSet` with the pointer already set on the current row  and should be only concerned with data mapping. It should not change the ResultSet (for instance by calling `next()`  as mentioned in the Javadoc) since this is the responsibility of the reader.